# Cannot access Symfony Framework from Remote Machine

Tags: ubuntu, symfony1, apache2

I just installed Symfony framework on my laptop (running Ubuntu 10.04) but I want to be able to develop it from windows machine.

Here is my apache config file for the site:

```
# Be sure to only have this line once in your configuration
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080

# This is the configuration for your project
Listen 8080

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/graffiti/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/var/www/graffiti/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf /var/www/graffiti/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
  <Directory "/var/www/graffiti/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

when I visit localhost:8080 I get the "Symfony Project Created" page.

On my desktop, when I visit the local IP 192.168.1.103:8080 I get a 404 error.

If I enable another site, I can access from my desktop just fine. I am stumped as to what I need to change to allow remote access to symfony.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

I had to replace all instances of

```
127.0.0.1:8080
```

with;

```
*:8080
```

and now it works.